# Threading Model

Tags: com, windows-ce, atl

I am going to develop an ATL COM for my device. We are using Win CE 6.0. My doubts are

- What threading models are supported by COM dll in WInCE?
- What threading models are supported by COM EXE in WInCE?
- Does WIN CE have support for DCOM?
- How can I check whether DCOM support is available in the WIN CE device I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- COM in Windows CE supports only in-process, free-threaded automation objects
- DCOM supports all threading models
- DCOM Remoting is not supported (removed as of 6.0 IIRC)

To see if your device has support, look in the \Windows folder at `ceconfig.h` and see if it contains `SYSGEN_OLE` (for COM support) and/or `SYSGEN_DCOM` (for DCOM support).

More info [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910765.aspx).